# Package not gets Included in jar file

Tags: android-source

I am trying to create jar file which includes some AOSP hidden api.
Android.mk is used to create jar. 
after run mma jar gets created in out/target/product/marlin/system/framework/test.jar 
Built jar  contain META-INF folder and classes.dex 
but proper package structure not gets created ex com.example.testsample

Android version 8

Androdi.mk is as follow

LOCAL_MODULE := testsample

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := src/AndroidManifest.xml

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,src)

LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

Please suggest solution as early as possible?